# How to provide some resource files for an android application?

Tags: android, assets

I'm writing an android application, which user can download some image files from server. There image files will be stored in android mobile.

Now I want to put some of image files inside the apk file, that user can start the application quickly after installing. I found I can put them into `assets` directory, but the directory is read only. When user download other image files, I need to store them into another directory.

So there will be two directories to store the image files, but they are the same type.

Is there any good solution for this case?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a downvote for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal for a listing of different places you can put data on Android.

You should put downloaded image files into one of three places, depending on your needs.

If the images are meant to be viewable by the user (e.g. downloaded photos), put them on the external storage. If they are meant to be user-interface elements or other crucial (but not user-facing) images, put them on internal storage. If they are meant to be cached for quick access but downloaded if necessary (e.g. temporary images like those found on a website), put them in the internal cache directory (`Context.getCacheDir()`).

If you don't have a lot of assets, you can copy them to the target location when your program first runs (e.g. check for the existence of a certain file, and create that file when you are done setting up). Then you only have to check one place (unless it's the cache dir, in which case you can't guarantee that the files will stick around forever).

If you have a lot of asset files, I would use a two-stage lookup: consult your downloaded image directory first (so you can override builtin assets, for example), then consult your assets directory. This is also flexible enough to allow you to make use of multiple storage locations should you find the need.